# Please let us filter featured questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, filtering

It would be helpful if I could filter the featured questions based on newest, votes, and bounties.

Answer (score 4):

Until this gets implemented, if at all, you can use the following Stack Snippet to *filter* on votes and bounty amount. The result is ordered by creation date.

```js
(function () {
  var api = {
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/',
    endpoint: 'questions/featured',
    params: { 
      site: 'stackoverflow',
      pagesize: 100,
      order: 'desc',
      sort: 'creation',
      Filter: '!5RCKNPLUeBH1JPtG(3gTdNpmM',
      key: 'JBN9WXWxwrcnAj7WEEytmQ(('
      }
    },
      sites = [],
      siteIndex = -1;
    
    
  function createUrl(ap) {
    var ep = ap.url + ap.endpoint +'?',
     nv = [];
    $.each(ap.params, function (k,v) {
       nv.push(k + '=' + v);
    });
    return ep + nv.join('&');
  }
 
  function enableLoad(func) {
    $('#load').show();
    $('#load').one('click', func);
  }
   
  function createVotesCell(item) {
    return $('<td></td>').html(item.score);
  }  
  function createBountyCell(item) {
    return $('<td></td>').html(item.bounty_amount);
  } 
  function createTitleCell(item) {
    return $('<td></td>').append($('<a></a>')
                .attr('href', item.link)
                .attr('title', item.bounty_amount)
                .html(item.title));
  }
  function createRow(item)   {
   return $('<tr></tr>').append(
              createTitleCell(item),
              createBountyCell(item),
              createVotesCell(item)
            );
  }
  // load a page of featured questions
  function load(page, filter) {
    api.params.page = page;
    $.get(createUrl(api), function (data) {
      var i, 
          list = $('#fav'),
          item,
          next;
      for(i = 0; i < data.items.length; i = i +1) {
          item = data.items[i];
          if (item.score >= filter.score &&
              item.bounty_amount >= filter.bounty) {
            list.append(createRow(item));
          }
      }
      if (data.has_more) {
        next = function () { load(page + 1, filter); };
        if (data.backoff !== undefined) {
          window.setTimeout( 
            next, 
            data.items.backoff * 1000);  
        } else {
            next();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $('#go').click(function() {
    $('#fav').empty();
    load(
      1, 
      { 
        bounty: parseInt($('#bounty').val(),10),
        score: parseInt($('#score').val(),10)
      });
  });
  
}());
```

```css
#onhold div {
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  }

#load {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center; 
  cursor: pointer
  }

img {
  height: 1em;
  }
  
table { border: black solid 1px;  border-spacing: 0px; }
td { border: black solid 1px; margin:0px; padding:0px; border-spacing: 0px;}
tr { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
td::nth(2) {text-align:right}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error" style="display:none">
</div>
<div>
<label>Bounty >= :<input type="text" value="50" id="bounty" /> </label>
<br/>
<label>Score >= :<input type="text" value="0" id="score" /> </label>
<br/>
<button id="go">Search</button>
</div>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>bounty</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="fav">
</tbody>
</table>
```